# free database modelling software

Tags: database-design, tools

What is available in the realms of database modelling software that is free.  I am developing an SQLExpress database.

CA ERWin - community version
  although is free, I can't see an option to allow me to create a database, either using a direct connect or via creating an SQL script file.

Embarcardo ER/Studio - 14 day trial
  Can I reinstall this every 14 days?

What others are there, that will allow me to model my database and create a "create" script or "update" sql script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to a non-express version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

There are several choices:

- [SQL Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect) (download without registration from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/)). This is open source, but it seems there is no further development.
- [Oracle's Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html) (but it only supports Oracle, SQL Server and DB2. PostgreSQL for example is not supported)
- A free version of [TOAD Data Modeler](http://toadworld.com/Freeware/ToadDataModelerFreeware/tabid/637/Default.aspx) - although that has some serious limitations on the size of the model
- [Open ModelSphere](http://www.modelsphere.org/) a general purpose modeler (including UML) but can also be used for ER modelling

Answer (score 2):

Though it is intended for IBM products, [IBM Data Studio](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-studio/) does support non-IBM Databases. From what I can see it allows some design/modelling of databases. It is free. Maybe take a peek at it. Here are the [features and benefits](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-studio/features.html?S_CMP=wspace).

Comment: Thanks, that is more than helpful.  I might give DB2 express a go too.